# special character mysql - convert to "?"

Tags: mysql, character

I want to put in my MySQL this word: xxvęrspIøgx

When I insert this word the result is: xxv?rspIøgx

What I have to do to support this character: ę ?

Comment: what character set is used in your table? Try running this query `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` and paste the output in your question.

Comment: You can use `charset=utf8`

Comment: I'm using utf8.

INSERT INTO xx SET name = 'xxvęrspIøgx';

Warning Code : 1366
Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x99rspI...' for column 'name' at row 1

Answer (score 1):

I would be best to encode the word into UTF-8 before storing the word, then decode it from UTF-8 after you fetch it from the database. This was elements of the word/data are not lost between transit and storage.

Comment: done...using charset=utf8 with encode and decode works like a charm :)
tks

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem can be one of at least these two:

1. Your data is not configured to UTF-8 Character Encoding,
2. The **input** mechanism does not support UTF-8 (e.g. if command line us used, the "TERMINAL" was not configured.

Verify your DB configuration and make sure that the path (from your "client" interface and down till your "server" side are properly configured.